# Free for commercial use tools for .NET that can convert csv to excel and export excel to pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, pdf-generation

I've got a report being exported as `.csv`, and I need to offer two more formats of the report - `.xlsx` and `.pdf`, with added headers/footers/images.

Originally, my plan was to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to open the `.csv`, modify it with [`EPPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to add the header/footer/logo, and save it as an `.xlsx` file, then export it as a `.pdf` but the application is running within IIS, and **automating office server-side is not recommended or supported**.

**1)** Are there any free for commercial use tools for opening .CSV files and saving them as .XLSX?

- **EPPlus is the best option** for this, as I can open CSV files, edit them, and save as Excel, which meets my requirement.

**2)** Are there any free for commercial use tools for exporting an **Excel .XLSX file to .PDF**?

**3)** Is there a tool that can do both?

Comment: PDFClown or iTextSharp may be good for the PDF bit.  For excel, if using 2007 format you can create an XML file then zip it as an XLSX file - take a look at the results of extracting an XLSX file to get an idea of the structure.

Comment: I'll check out PDFClown but unfortunately iTextSharp isn't free for use in commercial projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To **read csv files** very easily and model based you can use filehelpers.

http://www.filehelpers.net/

And to **create excel** files you can use epplus which is really good:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/
EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx). 
GNU Library General Public License (LGPL)

To **create pdf** file you can use PdfSharp

http://www.pdfsharp.net/Licensing.ashx

PDFsharp and MigraDoc Foundation are published under the MIT License.

See the PDFsharp License.
See the MigraDoc Foundation License.

> PDFsharp and MigraDoc Foundation are Open Source and free to use
>   Copy, modify and integrate the source code of PDFsharp and MigraDoc Foundation in your applications without restrictions at all
>   This also applies to commercial products (both Open Source and Closed Source)
>   PDFsharp and MigraDoc Foundation will remain Open Source and free to use even in the far future

Comment: Thank you for the answer Nesim, I've began using EPPlus to read the .csv files, if you download their samples - it is covered in sample 9. MigraDoc looked like exactly what I was asking for but it doesn't appear to support xlsx files specifically, but perhaps some conversion can be done to XML. I will let you know.

Comment: As from v5 EPPlus require a Commercial license for commercial use.  More information here https://www.epplussoftware.com/Home/LgplToPolyform

Comment: v4.5 is still available as a nuget package and has .net core support

Answer (score 2):

To work with post-2007 excel files (.xlsx), I highly recommend [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've settled on EPPlus for the first half of the solution - will consider this for the future!